# Changing size of font in top navigation

Tags: magento2, php, navigation

On my site www.uitverkoop.tips you see a top navigation and side bar navigation. I want to have more categories, but then the top navigation uses to lines. So I want to reduce the size so that more categories can fit on the top navigation. 
But how and where can i make this change? I checked default.xml but i cant change it there.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

The actual font size is **14px**. add below code in your theme to make it **13px**

```
.navigation > .ui-menu > li > a span {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Check below screen shot, I've added extra category called "Hello World" and it fits into 1 line.

[image]

Comment: In which file do i need to add it?

Comment: `app/design/frontend/Sm/himarket/Magento_Theme/web/css/yttheme.css`

Comment: Will do it in the morning. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you Tell me how you added a extra categorie on my site?

Comment: yttheme.css is not in the path you provided. So I can't make changes

Comment: try to find this CSS in your theme `https://www.uitverkoop.tips/pub/static/frontend/Sm/himarket/nl_NL/css/yttheme.css`. Please do not change at this location.

Comment: I have found it, but it has a code with different layout. I can't post it here. Can I email it to you? Because I don't know where I can change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87284/discussion-between-anushka27-and-abhishek-panchal).